# Shebang (#!) not working in Python Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, python-3.7, shebang

I have 2 versions of Python 2.7 and 3.7 in Windows. Everything was working fine before I reinstalled them, but now it just defaults to 2.7 even though I have the script to run 3.7

I tried these different options:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!python3
```

Environment variables I tried

```
PATH = D:\python3\python (same directory as 'where python' command)
PY_PYTHON = 3
```

Also, if I just install the 3.7 version by itself, Python does not recognize the.py file formats by default (unrecognized file icons), that is until I install 2.7.

So if I just have 3.7 installed, I cant open the .py files directly from the command line without using the 'py -3' executable. Perhaps the solution to why it defaults to 2.7 can be explained by this? I just dont know how to fix it.

Comment: reassign what the `.py` extension calls with the context menu. In Windows shebangs aren't meaningful.

Comment: it doesnt matter, python.exe is still going to choose 2.7

Comment: On Windows, the shebang may not do anything by default (unless we're talking about cygwin, mingw or WSL), but you can make it meaningful by installing the Python Launcher for Windows and associating .py files with it: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Comment: python.exe is 2.7, python3.exe would be python 3.x

Comment: Thanks anyway guys, and also referring me to the documentation. I will just use the 'py' executable as that still works.

Comment: you have to give the full path or the executables in the path